# Hide chart if more than 5 cells are empty

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a project, where i need to show a lot of charts. However some charts are lacking data, therefore i need to hide rows containing the certain charts if more than 5 cells are empty.

I have already hidden some cells in another project, but it was not based on charts. It was just a single cell.
The code here was basically, whenever referencing gave error.

```
For RowCnt = BeginRow1 To EndRow1
 If IsError(Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value) Then
  Rows("7:16").EntireRow.Hidden = True
 End If
Next RowCnt
```

Let's say i have 10 cells creating a chart, the chart fills out 15 rows.
Then i need a code that checks these 10 cells.

```
If more than 5 cells are empty Then
Rows("0:15").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
Next RowCnt
```

How do i handle this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `COUNTIF`

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, "") > 5 Then
```

where `rng` is a range that contains your 10 cells.

I would prefer the other way round though, where you count the non-empty cells

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, "*") < 5 Then
```

Now `rng` could be the entire row and you are not limited to 10 values.

btw, you don't need to use `.EntireRow` for a `Rows(...)` range. It already consists of entire rows.